# How can I print OSM map in EPSG:4326?

Tags: mapfish-print

I'm using MapFish Print 3 to print my map. All working fine when I use these parameters:

```
    "overviewMap": {
    "layers": [ 
      {
        "baseURL":"http://10.210.134.57/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        "opacity": 1,
        "type":"OSM",
        "imageExtension": "png",
        "tileSize":[256,256],
      }
    ]
  },    
    "map": {
      "dpi": 600,
      "projection":"EPSG:3857",
      "rotation": 0,
      "longitudeFirst": true,
      "scale": 15000000,
      "layers": layersToPrint
    }
```

but all my maps are in EPSG:4326 and I cannot use EPSG:3857 here because all my OSM tiles become a blue square.

How can I reproject OSM layer in MapFish to use EPSG:4326 in a OSM layer?

Comment: you'll need to reproject them before you send them to mapfish

Comment: Thanks Ian. I'm passing the OSM tiles thru my MAPPROXY as a WMS service and then reproject it. Now its working well.